# Java extension return a Bitmap(image) as a Byte Array as a String and I need to display the image in my Game. How?

Tags: java, arrays, bitmap, surface, game-maker

so I have a java extension( java code: https://pastebin.com/cpwf5LzT ). It has 1 function and the function have 1 argument that is a `String` called `fname`. And it returns a `String`. The function should get the file from the path of `fname` and if it's an image file, get it as a `Bitmap`. then I change the `Bitmap` to a byte array( `byte[]` ) and then the byte array to `String` and returns it.

The Extension works fine, but my problem is that I don't know how to change the `String` variable the function returns to a byte array and the byte array to sprite or paste it on a surface.

So can anybody with some knowledge about that kind of stuff can help me with that? Thanks!

**UPDATE #1:**

So I managed to add the Output String into a buffer and draw it but this is how it turns out compared to the original image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRs6k.png)

Tho if I make a new sprite, draw the sprite to a surface and gets the bitmap of the surface to the buffer, it turns out fine...

This is the code I used: https://pastebin.com/KhPhVr5p
(The load_image function is the function of the java extension)
(The draw_buffer function is a function that uses [this extension's functions](https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/assets/5344/buffer_getpixel) and should draw the buffer)

Maybe it's because of the buffer_getpixel extension? What can I use to replace it?

Comment: It was not very clear to me, are you trying to change the fname string passed as a parameter in load_image?

Comment: @JulianoPacheco I am trying in the GameMaker code after I get the output of the java extension's function String to bring it back into a byte array and draw the bitmap to a surface or as a sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple issues here,

- buffer_*_surface functions expect raw RGBA data, not a PNG file.
- You are returning the contents as a string, which could have issues depending on how NUL termination is handled. If your file gets cut off (after you fix the format), try encoding it as base64 instead.

Comment: How do I change the format to raw RGBA data from PNG file? I looked at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat but it looks like there is only: JPEG, PNG and WEBP

Comment: Also I check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config and RGBA_F16 looks similar to what you talked about. But it says `Each pixels is stored on 8 bytes` and I'm pretty sure GameMaker uses just 4 bytes for each pixel. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You would likely want to use [copyPixelsToBuffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)) instead of compress(...)